# Recover deleted Excel file

Tags: excel, recovery

A strange thing happened. A file my father was working in one of his Excel files was corrupted while he was saving it, resulting in the file being deleted.

Of course he didn't delete the file himself. Needless to say he came to me to find a solution.

So after some Googling I came up with a file recovery tool (PC Inspector File Recovery) and I found a deleted file.

The only problem is, the size of that file is less than 1kB, but it is an .xlsx file. Among that file there are also two other .tmp files, one is dating from a minute after the .xlsx-file was last edited, the other 6 hours later from the .xlsx-file. Both files are 171kB in size.

I'm suspecting the data from the original excelfile is in those files (I think the second file, is some copy of the first tmp file).

Does anyone know if I can restore these tmp-files into the original Excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just renaming it from .tmp to .xls and seeing if it would open?

Comment: Thanks a lot, really helped us out of the stuff that hit the fan :)